# Need to switch over an index formula into VBA to allow me to return true blanks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that takes data from reports. Sometimes there can be 4 numbers included and other times 50 relevant numbers.

Using `XLookup` with all the potential labels, and returning numbers if in the imported report.

Currently using this formula to scrub the data free of irrelevant number & label.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(DATA!C:C,SMALL(IF(DATA!D:D<>0,ROW(DATA!D:D)),ROWS(DATA!$D$2:D3))),"")
```

However, when I copy and paste in VB using:

```
Sheets("CALC").Select
Range("W3:W9" & Range("W1").End(xlDown).Row).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("FORM (3)").Select
Range("B20").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=True, Transpose:=False
```

I get the cells not filled in, that potentially could've been filled in, as blank but not true blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Added this in afterwards and it looks like it did a quick fix for me.

```vb
Range("B20:L80").Select
For Each cell In Selection
If cell.Value = "" Then
cell.ClearContents
End If
Next
```